# Where can I find information on Linux device driver parameters?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules

I want to work on Linux module programming (Device Drivers). And as a my college project I have to do profiling or benchmarking of a kernel modules based on various parameters. Everywhere I looked, I found info on how to write device drivers, whereas I want info on what parameters affect the performance of any specific driver/module. I also want to know how can I change them to test their various values.

Comment: Do you mean driver-specific parameters, or are you thinking more along the lines of "how does migration_cost=1000,2000,3000 affect the tg3 driver"?

Comment: @mattdm yeah, I want to know driver-specific parameters.........

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the driver-specific parameters, there's several places you can find information.

1. Hopefully there is some information in the [kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/). This is great for some stuff, sparse for others, and totally not there for most drivers.
2. Run `modinfo` (maybe with `-F param` or `-F parm`), which hopefully will give helpful one-line descriptions of parameters.
3. Find the [source code for the driver](http://lxr.linux.no/) and look for helpful inline documentation.
4. Search for a possible web site organizing development of that driver (for example [alsa project](http://www.alsa-project.org/) for sound).

And, of course, where things are vague, there's always empirical testing — try it and see.