# sources for doing profiling of kernel portions?

Tags: linux, kernel, drivers, profiling

Related to [my previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9567/where-can-i-find-information-on-linux-device-driver-parameters). I did not find any specific driver for which I can do profiling and benchmarking. However there is a one driver jffs2 filesystem for flash devices but I didn't know about any specific profiling tool and is it possible to do profiling without having flash device(that means for virtual hardware). And please tell me if we can do profiling (by changing various parameters) test for other kernel portions like memory management and process scheduling and what are the sources to study about it and profiling tools to do it efficiently and accurately.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part with that file system is it used an MTD device for storage which is neither a block nor character device.  The YAFFS2 filesystem has a dummy MTD device that stores data in an in-memory virtual NAND Flash.  You can probably borrow it and coach it into working with JFFS2, but I'm not sure how useful it will be for profiling when the virtual hardware is hundreds of thousands of times faster than real hardware.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about profiling and this will also not be accepted by our teachers. So I think to leave this idea and do profiling on other kernel portions. So if you have any info about memory management, process scheduling etc then please let me know...